# Consume a std::future by connecting a QObject

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11

I have some existing code that uses `std::future`/`std::promise` that I'd like to integrate with a Qt GUI cleanly.

Ideally, one could just:

```
std::future<int> future{do_something()};
connect(future, this, &MyObject::resultOfFuture);
```

and then implement `resultOfFuture` as a slot that gets one argument: the `int` value that came out of the `std::future<int>`. I've added this suggestion as a comment on [QTBUG-50676](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50676).  I like this best because most of my future/promises are not concurrent anyway, so I'd like to avoid firing up a thread just to wait on them. Also, type inference could then work between the future and the slot's parameter.

But it seems to me that this shouldn't be hard to implement using a wrapper Qt object (e.g., a version of `QFutureWatcher` that takes a `std::future<int>`). The two issues with a wrapper are:

1. the wrapper will have to be concrete in its result type.
2. the watcher would have to be concurrent in a thread?

Is there a best-practice to implement this sort of connection? Is there another way that can hook into the Qt main loop and avoid thread creation?

Answer (score 1):

`std::future` is missing continuations.  The only way to turn the result of a `std::future` asynchronously into a function call delivering the result is to launch a thread watching it, and if you want to avoid busy-waiting you need one such thread per `std::future`, as there is no way to lazy-wait on multiple `future`s at once.

There are plans to create a future with continuation (a `then` operation), but they are not in C++ as of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) let alone [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

You could write your own system of future/promise that mimics the interface of `std::future` and `std::promise` that does support continuations, or find a library that already did that.

A busy-wait solution that regularly checked if the future was ready could avoid launching a new thread.

In any case, [`std::experimental::then`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/then) would make your problem trivial.

```
future.then( [some_state](auto future){
  try {
    auto x = future.get();
    // send message with x
  } catch( ... ) {
    // deal with exception
  }
} );
```

you can write your own `std::experimetnal::future` or find an implementation to use yourself, but this functionality **cannot be provided** without using an extra thread with a `std::future`.

Comment: I'm ok with busy-waiting if there is an event loop anyway (as in QT), it can check every time around the loop and deliver the callback without spawning a thread. Edit: I would love to have continuations available though.

Comment: @clord Event loops are not busy waiting; they idle most of the time.